# Disable click on angular2-ui-switch under certain conditions

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am using angular 2 ui-switch:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-ui-switch

Under certain conditions, I want the switch to stay disabled even when I click on it. I can keep the switch disabled by default but when I click on it, it changes the state on the UI. Is there a way I can prevent it from changing the state when clicking on the switch?

My switch looks like this:

```
<ui-switch size="small" [checked]="getEnabled()" (click)="toggleSwitch($event)"></ui-switch>
```

getEnabled() is the method that returns true/false to decide whether the switch should be enabled or disabled. I am trying to figure how to have the click disabled under certain conditions, lets say when some variable is true, I disable the click on the switch so that nothing happens when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are after is disabling the firing of the click event function conditionally, then you can do the following:

```
<ui-switch size="small" [checked]="getEnabled()"
     (click)="someCondition ? toggleSwitch($event) : null"></ui-switch>
```

On the other hand, I can't see why the following shouldn't work:

```
<ui-switch size="small" [checked]="getEnabled()" [disabled]="someCondition"
     (click)="toggleSwitch($event)"></ui-switch>
```

Comment: setting (click)="null" does not disable the click event. It still keeps switching the state on UI, everytime I click on it

Comment: @user1892775 Try putting that conditional statement also for your checked binding: [chekced]="someCondition ? getEnabled() : null"